# How to add a media type to drupal_add_css in custom module

Tags: theming, 6

I’ve got a question about adding CSS to a custom module.

Originally I’ve been given this line:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)"    href="mobile.css"
```

And I’ve converted it into:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'savingsscore') . '/css/mobile.css', 'screen and          (max-width: 640px');
```

The file is being attached, but the media setting is wrong and I don’t know what it should be. I’m in Drupal 6.

Thanks!

Comment: before delving into this further, can you let us know what media setting/actual css link it is generating in error?  reason I ask is you have either something really obviously wrong or just a cut and paste glitch in your question above.

Comment: It wasn't generating an error per se. But instead the css was still effecting screens beyond 640px in width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drupal_add_css() is defined as:

```
drupal_add_css($path = NULL, $type = 'module', $media = 'all', $preprocess = TRUE)
```

and in your example, you are doing:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'savingsscore') . '/css/mobile.css', 'screen and          (max-width: 640px');
```

which appears to have two problems:

1. You are skipping the $type argument,
2. You aren't closing the max-width parenthetical.

I'd suggest trying:

```
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'savingsscore') . '/css/mobile.css', 'module', 'screen and (max-width: 640px)');
```

and seeing it that fixes things up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the media query inside your style sheet?

Wrap everything in:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
  /* Contents of mobile.css goes here. */
}
```